# Thread safety in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I suspect this applies to general ASP.Net too but I am not sure.

If I have an action method on a Controller, say MyController.DoSomethingExciting and three clients hit it at "the same time", is it intrinsically thread safe, or do I need to do something to ensure that the three concurrent calls don't interact with each other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Local variables in that method will be per-call. I presume (don't know MVC) that the Controller instances are per-request, so any instance members would be safe.

But if there are any static or other shared members, then they are not safe.

Comment: Does a controller instance being per request, make it thread safe? Or is there a way an instance of a controller might be used by multiple threads in the same request? I want to make sure if I give my controller a private variable, that it is thread safe.

Comment: An instance member of a controller instance should be thread-safe, as far as I know. But be certain that all of the resources that the controller uses are actually thread-safe. Again, note that I don't _know_ that the controller instance is per-request.

Answer (score 2):

if the method instantiates all its own variables and does not use any static members then it should be ok in all cases.

It the object is referenced by multiple threads at once and it reads some class level variables multiple times that could be modified by another thread inbetween reads then there could be a problem.

If it only reads data once and doesn't write anything at the class level then multi threading is unlikley to be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. Depends what you mean by "thread safety".

Suppose for example that they share an Entity Framework, say "db", and they work on some table. since you called your controller "MyController" lets call this db.MyTable
Each request summons a different instance of MyController. So far, thread safe. Each controller creates an instance of MyEntities db = new MyEntities(); So far thread safe. but since db.MyTable is of type IEnumerable<MyTable> they interact with each other. Suppose they work on the same entity in the database (without locks), say db.MyTable[0] - they'll overwrite each other ("last one to save wins").

3 users of your site will have three independent pointers (in the stack) pointing to the same place (in the database). It's not a thread issue. It's a data lock issue.

Comment: @colin-desmond Ask yourself - can two people in my system actually use the same resource (such as the same data entity) and try to write (update) it together?