# Is MVC4 Action Is Thread Safely?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using asp.net mvc4,  but I has a question about Action, Is the Action is Thread safely? I mean when 2 request is coming , Is that possible 1 request is handle but not finish, second request start handle?

Or if It is thread safely, wait for finish one request and another request?

Thanks.

> **Update1:**
>
> Looks like it's not thread safe. I have a action on Controller. in the action 5 method has been execute. (1,2,3,4,5). there is 3 request come together(A, B,C).
>
> there is my log display, these execute order:
>
> > A-1 B-1 C-1 A-2 A-3 B-2 B-3 B-4 B-5 C-4 C-5 A-2 A-3 A-4 A-5
>
> Because I need check data on 1 method, if the data not found, I will
>   write it on method 5. If execute not use thread safe, it will write 3
>   data.(because all not found data on method 1, also all not wait finish
>   together......)
>
> **Update2:**
>
> Maybe I'm confuse about Thread safe, but Thanks friends helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that possible 1 request is handle but not finish, second request start handle?

Of course, otherwise your website could effectively handle only one page view at a time.

You will have to make **your code** thread-safe. See for example [how to lock an asp.net mvc action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901048/how-to-lock-an-asp-net-mvc-action), or you could for example create a lock in your database which your code has to query.

Comment: if it will not finish and start another, Why some people still say it's  thread safe?

Comment: Because [controller instances are thread-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103745/thread-safety-in-asp-net-mvc), which means you can use private variables that won't be affected by other requests (unless they are static). So while **the MVC framework itself** promises to be thread-safe, for **any code you write, you** will have to determine and safe-guard that.

Comment: So, one more question: if I'm use lock to handle my current issues, Is there a performance problem?

Comment: It will make sure only one user can execute a request to the action(s) using that lock, which depending on the number of users and actual processing time of the request can become a problem.

Comment: @qakmak `if it will not finish and start another, Why some people still say it's thread safe?`  The way you phrase this makes me think you're not understanding what [thread safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) actually is.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Controller instances are `thread-safe` because new controllers instance will created for each request. So the concurrent calls will not interact with each other.

But `Static` or `Shared` resources are not `thread-safe`.

Comment: you mean 2 request access action same time, not will execute same time(when one of them execute to middle , changed to another start execute) right?

Comment: Each request creates a new instance of controller and actions are inside controller. So the concurrent calls will not interact.